# Why is this a valid pattern that can be used to recognize a String as an IP-Adress ? java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java

In my coding challenge I have the following problem:

Write a class called MyRegex which will contain a string pattern. You need to write a regular expression and assign it to the pattern such that it can be used to validate an IP address. Use the following definition of an IP address:

IP address is a string in the form "A.B.C.D", where the value of A, B, C, and D may range from 0 to 255. Leading zeros are allowed. The length of A, B, C, or D can't be greater than 3.

I looked up [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) beacuse I've never worked with patterns...

After a while I looked up whats the solution and a valid one is this:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String IP = in.next();
            System.out.println(IP.matches(new MyRegex().pattern));
        }

    }
}
class MyRegex {
    public String pattern = "((\\d|\\d\\d|[0-1]\\d\\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}(\\d|\\d\\d|[0-1]\\d\\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
}
```

Why is this working? What do the backslashes do and why are there dots etc. because when I read in the oracle docs, "\" is just a backslash and "." just means "any character" but according to the problem, the input should not contain just any characters so I don't understand this solution ... Whats going on here ?

Comment: \ is the escape character. In Java's regex you need to escape the escape character: `\\.`. Since the `.` is being escaped, it's seen as a normal `.`, not "any character".

Comment: You read in the oracle docs that \ is just a backslash? Can you link to that?

Comment: i mean double backslash just means backslash. sorry

Comment: That's correct for normal strings, but not for a regex.

Comment: Tried printing the value of `pattern` to system.out?